# MongoDB report an error while using `db.TestCollection.find({}).count()` to query the count of Collection

Tags: mongodb

```
TestUser> db.TestCollection.find({}).count()
[2021-06-01 11:02:58] com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of str
```

I have Five hundred million documents in TestCollection,MongoDB report an error while i was trying to get the count of it .What can i do to avoid that?
I have tried resetting the `max_connection_idle_time` to 6000ms , but it didnt work.

Thanks!

Comment: And i ve tried `db.TestCollection.find({"user_id":{"$gte":250000000}}).count` ， that worked!

Comment: So i was wandering  the count of collection is too big or not ?

Comment: What's the version of your MongoDB? And do you want the count of total documents or do you want count after specific filter?

Comment: the version is 4.0.3. And I didnt set any filter , just wanna know the count of total documents. Thanks ~

Comment: TBH it shouldn't cause any problem in that case because the system should be fetching it from the metadata of the collection, give this a try please, `db. TestCollection.estimatedDocumentCount({})`

Comment: OK . I will let u know.Thanks again, gandalf ^^

Comment: That works!!!!!

Comment: And by the way , i got some trouble while using `db.TestCollection.find({"user_id":{"$gte":**}}).count()` , that also report the same error. How can set the filter to make that query work ? As i tried `db.TestCollection.find({"user_id":{"$gte":250000000}}).count` and that one worked , but that because i just have 5 hundred million documents , what if i have more like 10 or 20 hundred million ?

Comment: Let me post this in detail, with reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MongoDB Version : 4.0

To start with the default count method, cursor count is getting deprecated since 4.0 due to some consistency issues.

Now the issues, the new methods for the count are broken into two parts

1. estimatedDocumentCount()
2. countDocuments()

The first one is used to get count of documents for the collection, it directly gives you the data from the metadata of the collection hence can be slightly delayed if your collection has a lot of writes taking place on it.

The second one entertains the query filter part but under the hood works using this method:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: <query> },
   { $group: { _id: null, n: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

The problem with this approach is for the DBMS to get you the count it has to manually count those documents, for which it will have to keep those documents in the WiredTiger Internal Cache, and hence on a big collection it would be slow and problematic, directly proportional to size of the collection.

For such scenarios try not repeating the count, use computed pattern discussed [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-computed-pattern).

There is a good possibility that in the current query you are running it is doing a manual scan and is struggling in getting all the data in WT Cache if it wasn't already there. For starters if you have to use query predicate and count then make sure there is an index over the search term but my vote, if possible, will always go to using computed pattern.

Comment: ok i will use them to do some queries. Thanks a lot!